# wkhtmltopdf works in command mode but not in Symfony2 bundle (knp_snappy)

Tags: symfony, wkhtmltopdf

I am generating **PDF reports** about the bundle `knp_snappy`, as it says in the title, so **wkhtmltopdf command works perfectly in command mode** but it does in the bundle, I get the following **error**:

```
The exit status code '127' says something went wrong:
stderr, "PROT_EXEC | PROT_WRITE failed.
```

I understand it is something related to **permissions** but do not know what I have to change to make it work.

my config.yml

```
knp_snappy:
    pdf:
        enabled:    true
        binary:     "/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf"
        options:    []
```

My controller:

```
$html = $this->renderView('PanelBundle:Default:hotel-booking-summary.pdf.html.twig', array(
            'summary' => $summary,
            'agency' => $agency
        ));

        return new Response(
            $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml($html),
            200,
            array(
                'Content-Type'          => 'application/pdf',
                'Content-Disposition'   => 'attachment; filename="file.pdf"'
            )
        );
```

I hope you can help me, **greetings** and thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

pls show

```
ls -la /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf
```

Actually you can try set permissions something like

```
sudo chown %your_ssh_user%:%your_www_group% /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf
```

Comment: [root@webserver01 bin]# ls -la /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 8301444 May 24  2010 /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf

Comment: you need to set exec permission from your web server group ( usually www-data or apache)

Comment: It has not worked, still with the same error. Note that I tested with more than one bundle (which depend on this binary) and always returns the same error.

Comment: Could you tell me more about setting permissions execution?

Comment: try to check web server error log about write permissions

Comment: Also I will advice to point write path to /tmp folder that has write permitions getOutputFromHtml($html, '/tmp/file.pdf'),

Comment: I do not have access to the logs, for some reason in the folder of my project virtual host only appears 'httpdocs' TT